# Can I install Ubuntu on P4 Machine with Windows XP

Tags: installation, ubuntu-minimal

Sorry for the question, but I am the new guy with ubuntu and dying to install it in my old pc. And just wanted to confirm that can I install it on my P4, 1GB ram, intel 82845 graphic controller machine or it's going to need more then this

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should try it from CD, and see for yourself. The graphics is that PC's weakest spot, so Xubuntu 12.04 would probably be a better option.

Answer (score 0):

Please visit this link to understand the minimum hardware requirements for latest Ubuntu.
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/QuantalQuetzal/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop#System_Requirements

You can install Ubuntu 12.04/12.10 on a with (P4 with 1 GB RAM), but your graphics hardware could create some problem. Just run Ubuntu from a Live CD or Live USB disk to get the actual picture.

But in my opinion Xubuntu/Lubuntu will be better option for you. Any of these two will give you faster and better performance than Ubuntu.